# Typescript + GraphQL Dataloader more strict types using generics or overloads

Tags: typescript, graphql, dataloader

I'm using GraphQL's dataloader and I'd like to make my return types more strict based on the keys that are passed in. How could I accomplish this? Feeble attempt below. I know why it doesn't work, but not sure what to fix. (same code exists in ts playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAHIEMC20C8UDk6YYANhPlAD4EBG6Adg+vgFCiSyIoDSEIAPABUM2KBAAewCPQAmAZ07I0WCAD4oeAN6NsALijCVAGihIZ++gkw0IcAL5tw0AILEyGgs9btoAISaMHvi+rCxI9FJwAGboAMbQ8EoAaugkCBAKmixQUESkEPqu+dlQdIyM+v7l6CwOLDIQsSTocNBN6HIKACLowOgAMgD26A1w-NwmSepZOSTDMgAUANZ8+twAlPpJtSwsUQj0scBIg-RQAOYQwEMjtkJiktLyiigiagvrUDNQAPQ-BgALJAKGSDDL0fDAKAAd0GcCWJhoCChKHwCmAAOg52GJAAtLioAg5NAMdBBBdpLYkLEoMBBlA5ADBtDaZioK1msdToykGBSldoRBpFAViAoAAyKAAN1S6QAdFASq1gAg4Gd6BAWT0+jdRvxEjw+EJVCYDcAUmkMgBtQQAXVUHx2ewORxOZ0w6HCHy+JVi3KhUS413mtg8l2DtzgjpyfygAHEkFLhRjeqzoDpoMCCHkyPgTKT2VdVWcfAymQgSDJ+VAimREcjTCiFLXoNQqkwcr7-bk3LgoIGlLrbHK5iMFtoVPpCL286ZzFAAIx2da7GP-BNJksA1MFjOmBT4MpMWcF5XF2lOMuDCtVmxQduBRU5P30ORQo+BPADlBDuAj+bjhmU4fswJhmPoABMy47DkQA))

```
type FruitName = 'apple' | 'banana'
type FruitKey<TName extends FruitName> = {name: TName, id: number}
type Apple = 'A'
type Banana = 'B'

interface FruitValues {
  apple: Apple
  banana: Banana
}

declare class DataLoader<K, V> {
  load(key: K): V
}

function getLoader<T extends FruitName>() {
  // This doesn't work, but it's the goal-- use the T generic to show the relationship between key & value. 
  return new DataLoader<FruitKey<T>, FruitValues[T]>()
}

function main() {
  const fruitLoader = getLoader()
  // Given that the name is 'apple', the return type should be Apple, but it is Apple | Banana  
  const apple = fruitLoader.load({name: 'apple', id: 1})

  // Given that the name is 'banana', the return type should be Banana  
  const banana = fruitLoader.load({name: 'banana', id: 2})
}
```